# Can I use dis-similar HW for Win2008r2 DFS-R

Tags: windows-server-2008, dfs-r

The setup:

- Windows 2008R2 Ent on two machines.
- The roles on each server will include File Servers and DC's.
- The machines come from two different vendors (Dell/HP)
- The Dell is an Athlon and the HP is an Intel.
- Both have roughly the same speed CPU and 8GB of RAM.
- They have different Raid controllers, and more or less the same amount of disk space (roughly 6TB.)

Can the servers use different types of hardware? Is there any documentation about this?

The last question I have is about the network. Can DFS-R be forced to use a differen subnet from the regular network?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes no problem.......  how do I make this 30 characters long

dfsr doesn't care about the hardware, and different subnets are fine. You'll just need to get the site info straighten out.